# Java Expression Trees

Tags: java, linq, scala, jvm, expression-trees

Is there an equivalent of `.net`'s Expression Trees that underly LINQ for the `JVM`? I would like to implement some LINQ like code structures in `Scala` and I am wondering if I have to roll my own expression tree library also.

Update:
I am not interested in a linq equivalent itself. .net has a large set of expression tree tools that make it easy to dynamically compile code at runtime can have it be callable from your code. The project I want to undertake has no relation to databases. Expression tree's provide an easy way to describe code that operates on data.

If there is no library my other option I think is to create one that emits byte code.

Comment: For JAVA try Quare (codehaus). BUT, as long as JAVA doesn't support high order functions (functions as first class members) i don't believe these "libraries" will feel the real LINQ.

Comment: Steve - did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: No. We just went back to windows and used windows. For some stuff we used LLVM with c++ on unix. However we are isolating the java stuff and using .net for everything that requires dynamic codegen.

Comment: Something in that area is Java the annotation processing tool.... But that is designed for code generation, rather than modification. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989449/parsing-and-translating-java-8-lambda-expressions

Answer (score 4):

Since 2.10, Scala has macros, which give you access to abstract syntax trees of their arguments at compile-time: http://scalamacros.org/. Here are some examples of their usage including a sketch of LINQ: http://scalamacros.org/paperstalks/2013-12-02-WhatAreMacrosGoodFor.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I am aware of is Julian Hyde's [linq4j](https://github.com/julianhyde/linq4j) and [Optiq](https://github.com/julianhyde/optiq) libraries. They have an expression tree model, support a LINQ-like model of programming (subject to Java syntax) against many types of data sources.